# How can I force the window to open in a given desktop in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde4

Let's assume that I had opened a .txt file using Kate in Desktop 1 and switched to Desktop 2 afterwards. Now if I open another .txt file, again using Kate, I am automatically switched back to Desktop 1 and both files are opened in the same window.

I would like all windows to open in the desktop I'm currently working in. How can I force such a behaviour?

Comment: 4 years without an answer...